# Typescript pass variable as generic type parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a function that accept string or string array and return an object with keys of those string.

Here is the dummy function:

```
type myType<T extends string> = { [K in T]: string }
const myFunc = <T extends string>(param: T | T[]): myType<T> => {
    let result = <myType<T>>{}
    // some codes here...
    return result;
}
```

With the above code, I already achieved this:

```
let val = myFunc(['foo', 'bar']);
val.foo // valid
val.other // invalid
```

But if I pass a variable to the function, all string keys are valid:

```
let variable = ['foo', 'bar'];
let val = myFunc(variable);
val.foo // valid
val.other // valid
```

Is there a workaround so I could pass a variable but still working as what I expected?

Comment: I think you need something along the lines of `string extends T ? never :` but I don't know what the syntax is for that

Answer (score 2):

When you create a variable `let variable = ['foo', 'bar']` the type of `variable` becomes `string[]` and you lose the knowledge of the specific strings in the array.  You need to use `as const` in order for Typescript to interpret `variable` as fixed tuple of string literals `'foo'` and `'bar'`.  Since this fixed tuple is `readonly`, you also need to modify your function to accept `readonly` arrays.

```
const myFunc = <T extends string>(param: T | readonly T[]): myType<T> => {
```

```
let variable = ['foo', 'bar'] as const;
let val2 = myFunc(variable);
val2.foo // valid
val2.other // invalid
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Nl0eQN)

Comment: Is there a way to not using the `as const`? It's easy to forget adding it and there is no error thrown.

Comment: Well you can pass it directly to the function, but you've already said that you don't want to do that.  You can assign an explicit type `let variable: ['foo', 'bar'] = ['foo', 'bar']`.